# Create a Docker volume in a different partition

Tags: docker

I have 2 partitions : partition A with containers and partition B with data and other relevant things. I would like to know if it is possible to create a volume from a container running in partition A to a directory based in partition B ?

NB : I do not want any data in my partition B

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: That is not an answer. Please provide details if you say it is possible...

Comment: @RafałLudwiczak Some details would be great ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it for example by using docker-compose https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

```
volumes:
  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /var/lib/mysql

  # Specify an absolute path mapping
  - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql

  # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
  - ./cache:/tmp/cache

  # User-relative path
  - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro

  # Named volume
  - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Just set an absolute path.